# Double Ended Queue, Call by Reference (Create Header)

Tags: c, list, pointers, malloc

i have a simple problem with my c code .... I want to call the variable with call by reference.

I have this function:

```
void createHeader(HEADER *yourHeader) 
{
yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
if (yourHeader == NULL)
    printError();
yourHeader->first = NULL;
yourHeader->last = NULL;
yourHeader->length = 0;  
}
```

My main-call:

```
createHeader(&header);
if (header == NULL)
    exit(-1);
```

Now I have the following problem: "The program '[6044] My-C-Project.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)", so that means my function createHeader doens't work ... Can someone please explain what's the mistake is?

Regards

Alex

Comment: `yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));` This locally overwrites whatever pointer you passed to the function, so `createHeader()` has no external side-effects (beyond leaking memory)

Comment: ahhh okay overwritting ... so normally i should initianlize it with *yourHeader? or how do i deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function to:

```
HEADER *createHeader(void) 
{
    HEADER *yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
    if (yourHeader == NULL)
        printErrorAndExit();
    yourHeader->first = NULL;
    yourHeader->last = NULL;
    yourHeader->length = 0;
    return yourHeader;
}
```

Use:

```
Header *header = createHeader();
if (header == NULL)
    exit(-1);
```

Alternatively, use a pointer to a pointer as the argument:

```
void createHeader(HEADER **yourHeader) 
{
    *yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
    if (*yourHeader == NULL)
        printError();
    (*yourHeader)->first = NULL;
    (*yourHeader)->last = NULL;
    (*yourHeader)->length = 0;
}
```

Use:

```
Header *header = NULL;
createHeader(&header);
if (header == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

These two techniques can be applied to most 'allocate pointer' operations — creating linked lists is a particularly common variation.  Note that `fopen()` and `fclose()` match the first model; the allocator (`fopen()`) takes some arguments to tell it what to do and the function returns a pointer to a structure that can be used and eventually passed to `fclose()` for release.

Note that `printErrorAndExit()` must not return.  Or, if it does, the functions have to be revised:

```
HEADER *createHeader(void) 
{
    HEADER *yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
    if (yourHeader == NULL)
        printError();
    else
    {
        yourHeader->first = NULL;
        yourHeader->last = NULL;
        yourHeader->length = 0;
    }
    return yourHeader;
}
```

It might be better for the function not to print any error message — that limits its reusability, in general.

```
HEADER *createHeader(void) 
{
    HEADER *yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
    if (yourHeader != NULL)
    {
        yourHeader->first = NULL;
        yourHeader->last = NULL;
        yourHeader->length = 0;
    }
    return yourHeader;
}
```

The alternative design should probably return a status instead of nothing, so you can test the function result directly:

```
int createHeader(HEADER **yourHeader) 
{
    int rc = 0;
    *yourHeader = malloc(sizeof(HEADER));
    if (*yourHeader == NULL)
        rc = -1;   /* Or perhaps errno */
    else
    {
        (*yourHeader)->first = NULL;
        (*yourHeader)->last = NULL;
        (*yourHeader)->length = 0;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Use:

```
if (createHeader(&header) != 0)
    …report error and bail out…
```

Using 0 for success and non-zero for failure is very common (many Unix system calls fall into this category).  Very often, a negative return value indicates failure, especially if a positive value can be used for success — think `open()`.  But the POSIX pthread functions frequently return a positive error number on failure and zero on success.

Comment: Thank you, thank you for putting so much effort to make such a good and 
understandable answer! :-)